# How can I pass Data from Hub to view using signalr

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, signals

[image]

Why is the MessageReciever function not working given the class Myhub I want to display time on the span feeding from the signal R Function BroadCastServerTime()?

[image]

Comment: Please paste code into your question instead of linking screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your signalr code with JQuery onReady event. Like:

```
    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $.connection.myHub.server.broadCastServerTime();
        });

        $.connection.myHub.client.MessageReceiver = function (message) {
            $('#serverTime').text(message);
        }
    });
```

This way your code only executes when JQuery is loaded and SignalR hub is loaded. Currently your signalr code does not wait for jquery or signalr hubs to get loaded.

Also make sure your MyHub code is sending the datetime to the MessageReceiver.

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void BroadCastServerTime()
    {
        Clients.All.MessageReceiver(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```